# ImageView not getting adjusted according to screen Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on android application. I have used Listview in one of activity which shows Two image views  and text views. The view should look as follows and in big screen looks fine but on small screen image takes most of space.

Nexus 4 Screen: But if you see images in following ss images are not aligned properly also if textview is bigger.

[image]

On Small Screen image acquires most of space. It looks bad as follows:

[image]

I want it to be consistent across in terms of layout.

Following is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <com.wallie.imagview.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categorylistname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categorylistcount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#777777"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryseeall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:src="@drawable/see_all" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SquareImageView is my custom class with following code:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }
}
```

Help will be really appreciated.

After making code changes looks like this in smaller screen

[image]

Comment: try changing onMeasure method to "super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);"

Comment: You have to given such fix width instead wrap_content.

Comment: @Gero same SquareImageView is used everywhere for this thing if i change it may impact how others things as well. Right?

Comment: @HareshChhelana didnt get you ?

Comment: @vo12 Yes. But your original SquareImageView, has no differences from the standard one (ImageView). Using "heightMeasureSpec" as both measure spec. parameters will definitely make your view's width equal to its height.

Comment: @Gero  I will try  but will this solve both problems?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryimage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categorylistname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categorylistcount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#777777"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryseeall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried in this also last image is not shown haresh

Comment: yeah did that but first imageview height is as it is in smaller screen big than expected it looks like as new image attached in question edited. on nexus 4 which i am testing looks fine but on smaller screen size looks big

Answer (score 0):

If you want always layout-ed 10:80:10 by `android:layout_weight` attr,
set `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

long expression:
`layout_weight` will use spaces without content width.
So if container is 800dp and `layout_width` are not `0dp`, first `ImageView`s are layout-ed normally (like imageview 400dp, text 300dp...) and then
separate spaces with weight.
if left space is 100dp, split `10:80:10` those space then ImageView get 410dp. oh no!

yes, maybe this time, `ImageView` with `wrap_content` is too large and weight attr gets nothing split to space.

If you getting wrong aspect ImageView, change the ImageView like this:

```
    <com.wallie.imagview.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryimage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"       <---- this
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_avatar"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>
```

Comment: @vo12 have you tried set height to match_parent OR add scaleType attr? And if you are using only squared image, no need to create custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onMeasure method to

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

And set layout widths to 0dp when setting its weight:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:weightSum="100">

        <com.wallie.imagview.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryimage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_avatar"
            android:layout_weight="10"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categorylistname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:typeface="sans"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categorylistcount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#777777"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:typeface="sans"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryseeall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:src="@drawable/see_all"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```